# Проблема Many 2 Many laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Ни как не могу разобраться с добавлением значения. Есть две модели Product и SpecificationName связанные many 2 many. Есть еще одна модель SpecificationValue,связанная с SpecificationName связью one 2 many.
Проблема возникает когда я добавляю товар,он добавляется в базу,все без ошибок,но значение не добавляется.

Вот, метод контроллера *ProductController*:

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = $request->input('name');
    $product->slug = $request->input('slug');
    $product->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
    $product->save();
    SpecificationName::findOrNew([
        new SpecificationValue($request->input('value')
    ]);
    $product->specName()->attach($request->input('spec_name_id'));
}
```

И еще 1 вопрос. Добавляю спецификации клонируя разметку. Все прекрасно добавляется,но когда пытаюсь редактировать товар,в спецификациях выводится только последнее клонируемые значения. Как сделать что бы все значения вывелись из базы?

Comment: в findOrNew передается id элемента

Comment: Дык откуда я возьму ид,если я хочу добавить новое значение

Comment: новое значение: `new SpecificationName()` или `SpecificationName::create()`

Comment: Я вас не понимаю:) можно по подробнее?:)

Comment: вы же уже так делаете: `$product = new Product();`, тоже самое только с этим классом

Comment: Все,понял:) спасибо

Comment: @apelsinka223 Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: Если используете new,то не забывайте вызывать save